# Using a html dropdown to determine user choice in Rails

Tags: mysql, html, ruby-on-rails

So I've been building my paste app on my local machine, and I've come across a small problem that has been bugging me. I need to figure out how to do syntax highlighting. In PHP, I could pass the user choice:

```
<select name="paste_syntax">
<option value="ruby">Ruby</option>
<option value="c">C</option>
<option value="html-xml">HTML/XML</option>
<option value="php">PHP</option>
</select>
```

and use $_POST to pass the variable chosen here, to highlight the syntax. E.g:

```
<pre class='mypostvar'>some code</pre>
```

However, in Rails, I'm not sure how to do this. I was thinking of creating a paste column in the paste table, which is linked to a paste_syntax table, containing all the paste syntax options. The 2 are linked. My question is, should I do this, or is there another way?
Help is appreciated!
~Adil

Comment: Are you looking to preselect the options that were previously selected?

Comment: Yes, so when the user selects 'Ruby' on the new paste page, they see their paste highlighted as Ruby code in the next page (in this case, the show paste page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I'd use syntax highlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) and then I wouldn't bother rails for this, but you can change the highlighting by changing class to your code, with some jQuery for example:

```
# coffeescript
jQuery ->
  $('#syntax').change (ev) ->
    selection = $(ev.target).val()
    $('#code').removeClass().addClass('brush: ' + selection);


-# haml
= select_tag :syntax, options_for_select([['ruby', 'ruby'], ['c', 'c']])
%pre#code{class: 'brush: ruby'}= "def ok \n  puts 'ok'\nend"
```